# Html content not loading properly in bxSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I am using [bxslider plugin](http://bxslider.com/) in my website.This slider has custom html content which is being fetched from server through rest calls in angularjs.There is one problem with this slider if the network connection is slow the cards are not displayed properly (cards on overlapped on each other and way bigger than expected).I've tried using onSliderLoad callback as suggested by multiple threads but it isn't working for me.This is the code in my js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
    }, 5000);
});
```

I've tried various suggestions from various websites but none is working for me....
This is the result I am getting
[image: This is what I am getting]

Comment: wait until all the rest calls are finished before setting the slider. Basically use promise or promise all.

Comment: This problem is observed only  when the network connection is slow,if network speed is good it works fine....